# CMD/Batch get active internet connection name

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I know how to get interface name

```
netsh interface show interface
```

[image: interface names]

I also know how to get wifi's names

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

[image: wlan profiles]

If I'm connected to Wi-Fi 2 adapter then I will be connected to one of the wlan profiles.

How can I can get same profile name to lan connection? It should be "TP-Link 2.4 2" according to my network connection settings. But if I try

```
netsh lan show profiles
```

[image: lan profile]

but still there is no name of ethernet. I wonder where it gets into windows 10, because I surely didn't type name of ethernet.

Ultimate goal is to print active connection name, so if ethernet 2 is active then TP-Link 2.4 2, if wi-fi is active then for example TP-Link 2.4

[image: lan name]

[image: network connections]

Comment: You may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398733/12343998)

Comment: That is almost exactly what I need. I can see from the profile list that my ethernet connection is there. Only question remaining is how to print active current connection. Because the script will list all connections and if you write guid of connection you are searching for, you'see if's there.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with this Batch code using the cmdlet `Get-NetAdapter` with Powershell v3

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Net Adapter Index
@for /f "tokens=1 skip=3 delims= " %%a in (
    'Powershell -C "Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Up' } | Select-Object -Property ifIndex"'
) Do (
    Set "Index=%%a"
)
echo NetAdapter Index = %Index%
pause
```

And if you want to get more information such `Interface` and `MACAddress`, you can try like this code below :

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Net Adapter Index,InterfaceDescription,MacAddress
@for /f "tokens=1,2,3 skip=1 delims=," %%a in (
    'Powershell -C "Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Where-Object  { $_.Status -eq 'Up' } | Select-Object -Property ifIndex,InterfaceDescription,MacAddress  | ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation"'
) Do (
    Set "Index=%%~a"
    Set "Interface=%%~b"
    Set "MacAddress=%%~c"
)
echo( Index = %Index%
echo( Interface = %Interface%
echo( MacAddress = %MacAddress%
Pause & Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I lack the means to test on ethernet connections - I can however demonstrate ways of catching and filtering output of netsh commands to variables, which you'll need to do for your ultimate goal.

- `For /F` allows capture of command output as it's executed
- Flag variables in conjunction with if condition checks can isolate sections of output of interest, or define output variables only when desired conditions are ,et.
- additional for /F loops can the be used to capture strings containing the Target value from the isolated output

```bat
 @Echo off
  IF not "!![" == "[" SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  For /F "Tokens=2,3,4 Delims=[]" %%G in (' Set Connection[ 2^> Nul ')Do Set "Connection[%%G][%%H][%%I]="
  (
   For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('netsh wlan show interfaces') Do (
    Set "Line=%%G"
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=: " %%i in (' Echo/!Line!^|findstr.exe /LIC:":" 2^> nul ')Do (
     Set "%%i=%%j"
    )
    If /I "!State!" == "Connected" If not "!Profile!" == "" (
     Set "Connection[!SSID!][!Name!][!GUID!]=Connected"
     Set "State="
     Set "Profile="
  )))
   (For /F "Tokens=2,3,4 Delims=[]" %%G in (' Set Connection[ ')Do (Echo Profile:%%G Type:%%H GUID:%%I)) 2> nul || Echo/No connection active.
```

Example output (one connection, GUID value modified from actual output)

`Profile:T3RRY  Type:Wi-Fi GUID:379552d8-1472-3b14-bf55-21eeb0c4eb1c`

Comment: That works fine for wifi, but for ethernet I got: "Environment variable Connection_ not defined"

Comment: I've changed the approach as best I can without seeing if active Ethernet connections are displayed in the netsh wlan show interfaces command. Are you able to give the updated script a try and let me know the if your ethernet connections are being returned in the netsh wlan show interfaces command If it still doesn't work?

Comment: The change in approach should catch only the interfaces that output a connected value for status